# Add eventlistener to multiple elements to execute multiple functions

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, element, addeventlistener

I am trying to add an eventlistener to 2 objects but only get it to work with 1. There are 2 textinputs which both should execute 4 functions on input. The first is my working single element code. There are many topics that already cover this problem and have many answers but I can't figure it out. Below I have copied some of the answers that I tried.

```
//code 1
document.querySelector("#textinput1").addEventListener("input", function WriteText () {
        document.getElementById("displaytext").innerHTML = document.getElementById("textinput1").value;
    });
```

```
//Answer 1 /// In both answer 1 and 2 I have put my Function() insides into the eventlistener function///

let elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll("#textinput1, #textinput2");

elementsArray.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("input", function() {

        document.getElementById("displaytext").innerHTML = document.getElementById("textinput1").value;

    });
});
```

```
//Answer2 // Tried it like this and putting the document.queryselector lines of both textinput directly between the []
    var Element1 = document.querySelector("#textinput1")
        var Element2 = document.querySelector("#textinput2")
    [Element1, Element2].forEach(function(element) {

   element.addEventListener("input", function() {
         document.getElementById("displaytext").innerHTML = document.getElementById("textinput1").value;

   });
});
```

Comment: It looks like both of those answers are correct for your purpose. What errors are you getting in the dev console of your browser (F12)?

Comment: `document.getElementById("displaytext").innerHTML = this.value;`

Answer (score 0):

The this keyword points to the the current elem object.

```
 let elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll("#textinput1, #textinput2");
 elementsArray.forEach(function (elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("input", function () {
  document.getElementById("displaytext").innerHTML = this.value;
  });
 });
```

Comment: I removed all my code and used your answer and it works. But I want 'displaytext' to only show the value of 'textinput1'. How do I get this to work?

Comment: I have tried to get the value of the right array element by .innerHTML = elementsArray[0]; but it doesnt work. I also tried to get it with .valueOf but also no succes

Comment: I did not understand what are you trying to achieve with that. you want that only a value of textinput1 be displayed no matter which input element you use ???